# UINavigationControllerのNavigationBarの高さは変更できますか？

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

iOS開発をしてます、objective-c初心者です。
コードから定義されたUINavigationControllerの、NavigationBarのheightを変更することはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、昨日時点までにご回答くださっていた方、時間が取れず反応が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。教えていただいた方法で無事解決しました。